# Android automation app to execute an action when a volume key is pressed but should not show ringer volume slider

Tags: gratis, android, automation

I'm looking for an app that can execute  an action when Volume Up or Down key is pressed. Not that I couldn't find any app but situation is bit different.

**OS support:** Jelly Bean or above.

**Pricing**: Freeware only

**Device status**: Rooted, Xposed framework installed.

The specific feature I request is that whenever the Volume key is pressed the ringer volume slider shouldn't be shown, neither should the volume level be affected.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

It's not an impossible task because [Xposed Additions Pro](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277) and [AutoInput](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120294/96277) can suppress the Volume key press from being passed to system. However, both requires you to shell out some money.

[QuickClick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blor.quickclickgold) seems to be a very popular app which caters specifically to actions being performed when Volume keys are pressed. Unfortunately, it shows that slider whenever I try to execute the action.

[MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) also suffers the same fate.

Comment: Hard without "shelling out some money" (which might be worth it, considering you'd otherwise "shelling out personal data" and have increased traffic for ads ;) My first thought was *Tasker*, of course, but that has its price as well. Don't know a candidate fitting all requirements – but as usual, be welcome to [check my corresponding app-list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation) :)

Comment: I've come to conclusion that before asking an app based question here I should consult first the great archivist Izzy for his huge collection of  archives. Thanks for the link. I couldn't find an app though, which does the job without getting paid. Hard luck as it seems. Anyhow, can Tasker achieve my objective without requiring any additional plugin?

Comment: Good idea, as usual :) I've just checked with the graph linked there: seems like the only hardware button *directly* supported by *Tasker* is the camera button – so I'm afraid, concerning volume buttons *Tasker* alone wouldn't do; I wouldn't even know any plugin for that (except for QuickClick). Maybe one of the [button re-assigners](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_546) can do? AFAIK only XPosed Additions (what's wrong with that?)

Comment: AutoInput is a good Tasker plugin that can do the job, paid it is though. As for Xposed Additions only, its [free version restricts you](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/page-up-and-page-down-in-web-pages-and-elsewhere#comment147235_118917) to set any per app-specific condition. You can only execute on Screen On/Off and Lock screen.

Comment: Conclusion: "Best things in life are free // best things for smartphones not necessarily". Sorry, I'm out of ideas then.